# REact js noob here, how do you change state object values while looping thru an array with their keys in it

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';



const values=['change','me']
export default class Mycomp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      
      this.state={
        'change': 0,
        'me': 0,
       }
      }

        clickhand(item,n){
        this.setState({item:n})//it assigns the given value to n but not to item so how do you loop ?
        };
       render(){
      return( 
        values.map((element)=>{return(
   <Button variant="contained" size="small" color="primary" style={{margin:'3px'}} 
onClick={()=>this.clickhand(element,(this.state[element]+1))}>
                      
                    +{this.state[element]}
                  </Button>)})

)}}
```

so how can i change the values in the state with a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState({item:n})
```

`item` here is considered as property name but not a variable which value should be used as property name.

try to change it to

```
this.setState({ [item] : n })
```

Comment: Can you try changing clickhand(item,n){ to arrow function. clickhand=(item,n)=>{